# Azure SMB File Share Permission Denied

Tags: azure, server-message-block, azure-storage

We have an SMB share set up in Azure.

Our infrastructure has an on-prem AD which synchronises with Azure AD and then there is an AADDS domain within Azure which has a copy of the user accounts.

If I log onto a computer within the AADDS domain as a user who has IAM read write access to the SMB share then it can be opened. If I try to access from a computer in the on-prem domain as that same user then it gives access denied. I can be logged onto my computer from the on-prem domain and access it as myself so I was assuming it would work for others, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

On the AADDS domain I ran the script like the one below in order to create an account in the Active Directory. I suspect it could be because the account doesn't exist on-prem? The thing is, how would I go about getting both domains to be able to access the SMB share without affecting what is already in place on AADDS?

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser

Import-Module -Name AzFilesHybrid

Connect-AzAccount

$subscriptionId = "<SUBID>"
$resourceGroupName = "<RESOURCEGROUP>"
$storageAccountName = "<STORAGEACCT>"

Select-AzSubscription $subscriptionId

Join-AzStorageAccountForAuth -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -DomainAccountType ServiceLogonAccount -OrganizationalUnitDistinguishedName "<OU_DN>" -OverwriteExistingADObject
```

BACKGROUND:

After more testing, it seems that there isn't a way to have authentication to work on two domains simultaneously against the same storage account. The reason why we require this is that the WVD app references a mapped drive. The users need to be able to transfer files to the same mapping from their local ad on-prem joined computers.

I looked into ways around this such as seeing if there is a way to publish the file explorer as an app, but can't seem to do that. If there were a file browser utility that came with the RD Client it would be perfect.

Comment: I've been looking into it further. I created a test storage account and then ran the script on on-prem ad to set up the authentication. It seems that it works in that users can authenticate to that account when on-prem, but when you log onto a computer in Azure ADDS then it doesn't authenticate. It seems that it is not possible for the authentication to work for both domains simultaneously. I will update the question with some background to explain the scenario in more detail and why this is required.

Comment: This is the response from Microsoft support:

"As I have checked internally and found that same storage account cannot be authenticated from two separate domains (different forests)."